# How do you catch the image URI when selecting multiple images from gallery?

Tags: java, android

I have a method that allows you to select multiple images from the native system gallery.

```
public void selectImages(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
}
```

How would you go about catching the URI image values?

Comment: `data.getClipData()` contains all as you can see in your link.

Answer (score 0):

Use below library for multiple image selection from the gallery. https://github.com/sangcomz/FishBun

FishBun is a highly customizable image picker for Android.
Use FishBun in an activity:

```
FishBun.with(YourActivity).setImageAdapter(new GlideAdapter()).startAlbum();
```

Comment: This is no answer to the question. It looks more like an add. You could have used a comment for it as you are completely off topic.